# Finding dimension of a subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$ that spans the list $\{(1,-1,1,-1),(1,1,1,1),(1,0,1,0),(0,1,0,t)\}$. Find the value of $t$ such that $\text{dim} W=2$.

I tried to solve it using matrix echelon and thats what i end up with
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0\\
0&1&1/2&1/2\\
0&0&0&t-1\\
0&0&0&0&\end{bmatrix}$$

i dont know if the answare will be the value of t

Comment: Ideas....?${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: want to know the values of the varible (t) that make the dimension of the subspace = 2

Comment: @Blocko That's clear from the question; you *should* have made some attempt, don't you?

Comment: @DonAntonio write the given vectors in row or column matrix and then find out the linearly two independent vectors from them changing the matrix into echelon or reduced echelon 
then find from there the value of "t"

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers.

Comment: @egreg thanks for editing

Comment: Hint: how many pivots should you have for the rank of the matrix to be 2?

Answer (score 0):

If $t=1$ then $\text{dim}W=2$.

We have then the following vectors: $$\vec v_1=(1,-1,1,-1),\vec v_2=(1,1,1,1),\vec v_3=(1,0,1,0),\vec v_4=(0,1,0,1).$$

Now,

$$\vec v_3=\frac12(\vec v_1+\vec v_2),$$
$$\vec v_2=\vec v_3+\vec v_4,$$

$$\vec v_4=\frac12(\vec v_1-\vec v_2),$$
$$\vec v_4=-(\vec v_1-\vec v_3).$$

That is, any triplets of the four vectors are linearly dependent. However, for example $\vec v_1$ and $\vec  v_2$ are linearly independent:
$$c_1\vec v_1+c_2\vec v_2=(c_1+c_2,c_2-c_1,c_1+c_2,c_2-c_1)=\vec 0$$

iff both $c_1=0$ and $c_2=0.$